# mySQL query using two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table (config) with the field 'type' in and another table (users) with the field 'status' in.

Some values for the field 'status' are blank.

I want to change the field 'status' to 'applied' ONLY if the field 'type' in the other table equals '3'.

Can you please explain how to do this query?

Comment: How do you know the user config type. Do you have a config id in user?

Comment: what is the relation between this two tables? (primary / foreign keys)

Comment: Can you please show the schema for these two tables, explaining which fields make the join.  *show create table config;* and *show create table users;* should do it.

Comment: Type is set database-wide. So the type is not related to actual users. We have a cluster of approx 250 databases each with the same structure. We will apply the query to all of them, only some of them are type 3.

Comment: And there isn't really any relationship apart from being in the same database, it is just two fields in two different tables.

Comment: If a config is not related to user in anyway, you cannot do what you ask.

Comment: If there is no relationship. your question has no meaning.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update table2
inner join table1 on table1.id=table2.id 
and  table1.type=3 
set status=applied
```

id is the common field in both the tables

Comment: Mysql's syntax for joining on updates is different than other DBMS.